# Solve differential equation, problem with integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation: $$(3i*t+2i-3)y''+(2+3t)y'-3y=(3-5i-3i*t)*e^{-t}.$$
First I started looking for a solution to $$(3i*t+2i-3)y''+(2+3t)y'-3y=0.$$

I found a solution: $$y=3*t+2.$$

Then I decided to use the Ostrogradsky–Liouville formula, and got a new equation: $$\left ( \frac{y}{3t+2} \right )' = C* \frac{(3i*t+2i-3)*e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2}.$$

Now I have to solve the integral $$\int \frac{(3i*t+2i-3)*e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2} dt.$$ Here I stopped; I don't know how to do it. WolframAlpha can, but it doesn't show a step-by-step solution, and I must do it myself.

So, can you help me solve the integral, or find another way? Maybe there's a solution without the Ostrogradsky–Liouville formula.

Comment: is it $3-4it$ on the right side of the ode ?

Comment: @isham sorry, i corrected $3-5i-3i*t$

Answer (score 3):

Hint for the integral, try to evaluate the derivative of $\frac {e^{it}}{3t+2}$

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to solve only the integral that you're stuck on.

$$\begin{align}I&=\int\dfrac{(3it+2i-3)e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2}\mathrm dt\\&=\int\dfrac{(3t+2)i e^{it}-3e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2}\mathrm dt\\&=\int\dfrac{\mathrm (3t+2)d(e^{it})-\mathrm d(3t+2)\cdot e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2}\mathrm dt\\&=\int\mathrm d\left(\dfrac{e^{it}}{3t+2}\right)\qquad(\text{Recognize the quotient rule?})\\&=\dfrac{e^{it}}{3t+2}+C\end{align}$$

**Another approach** could be...
$$\begin{align}I&=\int\dfrac{(3it+2i-3)e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2}\mathrm dt\\&=\int\dfrac{ie^{it}}{3t+2}\mathrm dt-\int\dfrac{3e^{it}}{(3t+2)^2}\mathrm dt\end{align}$$We focus on the second part of the integral now, and integrate by parts...

Let $u=-3e^{it}\implies \mathrm du=-3ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt$

And $\mathrm dv=\dfrac1{(3t+2)^2}\mathrm dt\implies v=-\dfrac1{3(3t+2)}$

\begin{align}I&=\int\dfrac{ie^{it}}{3t+2}\mathrm dt+\dfrac{e^{it}}{3t+2}+C-\int\dfrac{ie^{it}}{3t+2}\mathrm dt\\I&=\boxed{\dfrac{e^{it}}{3t+2}+C}\end{align}

Comment: Oh, I've found another mistake))) $(3t+2)^2$ , sorry
But your solution also part of the correct solution, the problem is that we have never used $Ei(u)$ before. I've googled that, and as a last resort i will use it. But is there any more elegant way?

Comment: @justastudent, well I see a couple of edits in the original question, but yeah the answer won't change too much. And yes, if the integral comes up as $\dfrac{e^x}x$, then we must use exponential integral.

Comment: @justastudent, hold on I see something in the integral :)

Comment: @justastudent check the answer now :)

Comment: Oh!!1 Its great

Comment: @justastudent, I've added a different approach too, see if that's any better for you

Comment: Can you help me with the last one??
$$\int \frac{(3t+2)(3-5i-3i*t)))*e^{(-i-1)t}}{(3i*t+2i-3)^2}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70782/discussion-between-awnon-bhowmik-and-just-a-student).